# db_index and unique=True on OneToOne relationship

Tags: django, django-sphinx

I'm extending django's User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, _(u"User"))
```

so, is it possible to use db_index=True and unique=True with user field? and then I need to implement search by username. I thought about Sphinx. Any thoughts on this? maybe some links with good tutorials? TIA

Comment: you don't have to put unique because its OnetoOneField

Answer (score 6):

Search by username would just be:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username="dave")
```

Also, I'm not sure what your second parameter is supposed to do; the declaration should look like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

All extra arguments to `models.OneToOneField` should be keyword arguments.

As cathy pointed out, `models.OneToOneField` implies `unique=True`. IIRC, this means Django will automatically create an index for this field. (You would need to explicitly set `db_index=False` if you *didn't* want the index.)

Comment: Thanx. that is what I wanted to know)))